# How to refresh JPA entities when backend database changes asynchronously?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, netbeans, glassfish

I have a PostgreSQL 8.4 database with some tables and views which are essentially joins on some of the tables.  I used NetBeans 7.2 (as described [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/70/websvc/rest.html)) to create REST based services derived from those views and tables and deployed those to a Glassfish 3.1.2.2 server.

There is another process which asynchronously updates contents in some of tables used to build the views.  I can directly query the views and tables and see these changes have occured correctly.  However, when pulled from the REST based services, the values are not the same as those in the database.  I am assuming this is because JPA has cached local copies of the database contents on the Glassfish server and JPA needs to refresh the associated entities.

I have tried adding a couple of methods to the AbstractFacade class NetBeans generates:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;
    private String entityName;
    private static boolean _refresh = true;

    public static void refresh() { _refresh = true; }

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
        this.entityName = entityClass.getSimpleName();
    }

    private void doRefresh() {
        if (_refresh) {
            EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
            em.flush();

            for (EntityType<?> entity : em.getMetamodel().getEntities()) {
                if (entity.getName().contains(entityName)) {
                    try {
                        em.refresh(entity);
                        // log success
                    }
                    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // log failure ... typically complains entity is not managed
                    }
                }
            }

            _refresh = false;
        }
    }

...

}
```

I then call `doRefresh()` from each of the `find` methods NetBeans generates.  What normally happens is the `IllegalArgumentsException` is thrown stating somethng like `Can not refresh not managed object: EntityTypeImpl@28524907:MyView [ javaType: class org.my.rest.MyView descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(org.my.rest.MyView --> [DatabaseTable(my_view)]), mappings: 12].`

So I'm looking for some suggestions on how to correctly refresh the entities associated with the views so it is up to date.

**UPDATE:** Turns out my understanding of the underlying problem was not correct.  It is somewhat related to [another question I posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980332/glassfish-postgresql-table-with-composite-two-part-primary-key-generating-co), namely the view had no single field which could be used as a unique identifier.  NetBeans required I select an ID field, so I just chose one part of what should have been a multi-part key.  This exhibited the behavior that all records with a particular ID field were identical, even though the database had records with the same ID field but the rest of it was different.  JPA didn't go any further than looking at what I told it was the unique identifier and simply pulled the first record it found.

I resolved this by adding a unique identifier field (never was able to get the multipart key to work properly).

Comment: Please post your `persistence.xml` minus any `<class/>` entries. In particular, the 2nd level cache controls.

Comment: Also, those aren't the full exceptions. There will be a cause chain leading to the *real* exception thrown by EclipseLink. Please show the EclipseLink exception and (if one was thrown) any underlying PgJDBC exception. If your application doesn't output them, look in the Glassfish logs.

Comment: Near-dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2400430/398670

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I recommend adding an `@Startup` `@Singleton` class that establishes a JDBC connection to the PostgreSQL database and uses [`LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) to handle cache invalidation.

**Update**: [Here's another interesting approach, using pgq and a collection of workers for invalidation](http://momjian.us/main/blogs/pgblog/2014.html#March_1_2014).

### Invalidation signalling

Add a trigger on the table that's being updated that sends a `NOTIFY` whenever an entity is updated. On PostgreSQL 9.0 and above this `NOTIFY` can contain a payload, usually a row ID, so you don't have to invalidate your entire cache, just the entity that has changed. On older versions where a payload isn't supported you can either add the invalidated entries to a timestamped log table that your helper class queries when it gets a `NOTIFY`, or just invalidate the whole cache.

Your helper class now `LISTEN`s on the `NOTIFY` events the trigger sends. When it gets a `NOTIFY` event, it can invalidate individual cache entries (see below), or flush the entire cache. You can listen for notifications from the database with [PgJDBC's listen/notify support](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/listennotify.html). You will need to unwrap any connection pooler managed `java.sql.Connection` to get to the underlying PostgreSQL implementation so you can cast it to `org.postgresql.PGConnection` and call `getNotifications()` on it.

An an alternative to `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`, you could poll a change log table on a timer, and have a trigger on the problem table append changed row IDs and change timestamps to the change log table. This approach will be portable except for the need for a different trigger for each DB type, but it's inefficient and less timely. It'll require frequent inefficient polling, and still have a time delay that the listen/notify approach does not. In PostgreSQL you can use an `UNLOGGED` table to reduce the costs of this approach a little bit.

### Cache levels

EclipseLink/JPA has a couple of levels of caching.

The 1st level cache is at the [`EntityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) level. If an entity is attached to an `EntityManager` by `persist(...)`, `merge(...)`, `find(...)`, etc, then the `EntityManager` is required to return *the same instance of that entity* when it is accessed again within the same session, whether or not your application still has references to it. This attached instance won't be up-to-date if your database contents have since changed.

The 2nd level cache, which is optional, is at the [`EntityManagerFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) level and is a more traditional cache. It isn't clear whether you have the 2nd level cache enabled. Check your EclipseLink logs and your `persistence.xml`. You can get access to the 2nd level cache with `EntityManagerFactory.getCache()`; see [`Cache`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Cache.html).

@thedayofcondor showed how to flush the 2nd level cache with:

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
```

but you can also evict individual objects with the [`evict(java.lang.Class cls, java.lang.Object primaryKey)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Cache.html) call:

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(theClass, thePrimaryKey);
```

which you can use from your `@Startup` `@Singleton` `NOTIFY` listener to invalidate only those entries that have changed.

The 1st level cache isn't so easy, because it's part of your application logic. You'll want to learn about how the `EntityManager`, attached and detached entities, etc work. One option is to always use detached entities for the table in question, where you use a new `EntityManager` whenever you fetch the entity. This question:

[Invalidating JPA EntityManager session](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2400430/398670)

has a useful discussion of handling invalidation of the entity manager's cache. However, it's unlikely that an `EntityManager` cache is your problem, because a RESTful web service is usually implemented using short `EntityManager` sessions. This is only likely to be an issue if you're using extended persistence contexts, or if you're creating and managing your own `EntityManager` sessions rather than using container-managed persistence.

Comment: Turns out the question I asked didn't correctly reflect the underlying issue I faced (See update in the OP).  However, this is certainly the best explanation of the problem I did ask.

Answer (score 8):

You can either disable caching entirely (see: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F ) but be preparedto a fairly large performance loss.

Otherwise, you can perform a clear cache programmatically with

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
```

You can map it to a servlet so you can call it externally - this is better if your database is modify externally very seldom and you just want to be sure JPS will pick up the new version

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but how do you receive your EntityManager/Session/whatever?

If you queried the entity in one session, it will be detached in the next one and you will have to merge it back into the persistence context to get it managed again.

Trying to work with detached entities may result in those not-managed exceptions, you should re-query the entity or you could try it with merge (or similar methods).

Comment: I tried what you suggested surrounding the call to `em.refresh(entity)` with `em.persist(entity)` and `em.detach(entity)`. It resulted in `Object: EntityTypeImpl@22507010:MyView [ javaType: class org.my.rest.MyView descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(org.my.rest.MyView --> [DatabaseTable(my_view)]), mappings: 12] is not a known entity type.`

Comment: When refreshing, no persist should be needed (there is nothing to save, just to receive). em.detach() will detach the entity (thus removing it from the context). Only em.merge() should be the way to go to add the entity to the context.

Answer (score -4):

JPA doesn't do any caching by default. You have to explicitly configure it. I believe its the side effect of the architectural style you have chosen: REST. I think caching is happening at the web servers, proxy servers etc. I suggest you read [this](http://odino.org/rest-better-http-cache/) and debug more.

Comment: JPA does not specify anything about caching; it's up to JPA implementations to specify caching. EclipseLink for example *does* have caching by default.