# Calling external program from PostgreSQL trigger

Tags: postgresql, notifications, listener

I would like to execute external program (such as .net c# console) when PostgreSQL trigger is fired. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Why my question was voted down? any reason?

Comment: Of course, I have been searching solution. I still cannot find better and faster solution. Any alternative solution is ok.

Answer (score 17):

Postgres cannot normally run external programs for security reasons.

The typical solution is to use [`NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) and have a daemon [`LISTEN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-listen.html) to it. There are solutions for every major scripting language out there ...

- Examples for Java from @Craig:  [How to refresh JPA entities when backend database changes asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258976/how-to-refresh-jpa-entities-when-backend-database-changes-asynchronously)
- [Relevant manual page for PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-get-notify.php).

Comment: Is the PHP example blocking? And what I want to continuously listen? Not just for one event, but for every event?

Comment: Apparently there is a queue of events that have not been listened to, so all one needs to do is rerun the listen query again after processing an event.

Comment: Link to the C++ (libpqxx) interface for this: [http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/4.0/html/Reference/a00208.html](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/4.0/html/Reference/a00208.html)

Answer (score 9):

Since Postgres 9.3 there is a solution for invoking external programs. It is - for security reasons - limited to superusers and IMHO intended for exporting data, rather than doing a "notification on trigger":

```
COPY (SELECT 1) TO PROGRAM '/bin/touch /tmp/created_by_postgres'
```

If you want to actually export data to the invoked programm, you can provide any SELECT or a table name instead of *SELECT 1*. The query results will then be passed to the invoked program via its standard input.

You can find documentation of the feature in the Postgres docs:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: Hello, could you please explain why you have two paths in your arguments `/bin/touch` and `/tmp/created_by_postgres`? Do you think this would work to execute an external python or shell script?

Comment: Alright, I understand that `PROGRAM` can actually run any shell command... Would you happen to know if there is a handshake between the postgres function executing the `COPY` method and the shell command executed by `PROGRAM`? Meaning the postgres function would wait for the shell command to complete before moving to its next task.

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.8) *"`COPY` naming a file or command is only allowed to database superusers or users who are granted one of the roles `pg_read_server_files`, `pg_write_server_files`, or `pg_execute_server_program`, since it allows reading or writing any file or running a program that the server has privileges to access."*

Answer (score 1):

You can execute external scripts from inside trigger function with an "untrusted" language, like plpythonu.
More details here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html

Trigger function example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION execute_python_script()
RETURNS trigger
AS $$
begin

import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['/path/to/your/bin/python', '/some_folder/some_sub_folder/script.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

end;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Trigger example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT ON table
EXECUTE PROCEDURE execute_python_script();
```