# How to reload configuration of Spring bean when particular database record is updated?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I am loading `keystore` in Spring WS via `JPA` from database.

```
@Bean(name = "keyStore")
@Primary
KeyStoreFactoryBean keyStore() throws Exception {

    try {
        KeyStore keyStore = keyService.keyStore();

        KeyStoreFactoryBean keyStoreFactory = new KeyStoreFactoryBean();
        keyStoreFactory.setPassword(keyStore.getPassword());
        keyStoreFactory.setLocation(keyStore.asResource());
        keyStoreFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return keyStoreFactory;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

}
```

This code works, but if I update keystore record in database, `KeyStoreFactoryBean` is not reloaded (obviously). I aware of `scope` anotation for beans but not sure what `scope` is best for this situation?

**How to "reload" this bean everytime database record is changed?**

Comment: Sounds like you want to have DB Change Notifications. This is probably database dependent. Here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258976/how-to-refresh-jpa-entities-when-backend-database-changes-asynchronously)

Comment: You mention JPA then promptly don't show any usage of JPA API